# Converting generic type to its base and vice-versa

Tags: c#, generics, casting, generic-list

Can someone help me with the conversion I am facing in enclosed code ... I commented the lines of code, where I am having problem. Is this even the right way to achieve this ... what I am trying to do, is forward responses of specified type to provided callback.

> **EDIT 1**
>
> I forgot to mention that Response and AFResponse are abstract classes,
>   which goes: >Response -> AFResponse -> concrete implementations of AF
>   layer messages

```
public class MessageBinder
{
    private class Subscriber<T> : IEquatable<Subscriber<T>> where T : Response
    {
        ...
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Subscriber<Response>>> bindings;

    public MessageBinder()
    {
        this.bindings = new Dictionary<Type, List<Subscriber<Response>>>();
    }

    public void Bind<TResponse>(short shortAddress, Action<ZigbeeAsyncResponse<TResponse>> callback)
        where TResponse : Response
    {
        List<Subscriber<TResponse>> subscribers = this.GetSubscribers<TResponse>();
        if (subscribers != null)
        {
            subscribers.Add(new Subscriber<TResponse>(shortAddress, callback));
        }
        else
        {
            var subscriber = new Subscriber<TResponse>(shortAddress, callback);

            // ERROR: cannot convert from 'List<Subscriber<TResponse>>' to 'List<Subscriber<Response>>' ... tried LINQ Cast operator - does not work either
            this.bindings.Add(typeof(TResponse), new List<Subscriber<TResponse>> { subscriber });
        }
    }

    public void Forward<TResponse>(TResponse response)
        where TResponse : Response
    {
        var subscribers = this.GetSubscribers<TResponse>();
        if (subscribers != null)
        {
            Subscriber<TResponse> subscriber;
            Type responseType = typeof (TResponse);

            if (responseType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (AFResponse)))
            {
                // ERROR: Cannot convert type 'TResponse' to 'AFResponse' ... tried cast to object first, works, but is this the right way?
                var afResponse = (AFResponse)response;
                subscriber = subscribers.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ShortAddress == afResponse.ShortAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                subscriber = subscribers.First();
            }

            if (subscriber != null)
            {
                subscriber.Forward(response);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Subscriber<TResponse>> GetSubscribers<TResponse>() where TResponse : Response
    {
        List<Subscriber<Response>> subscribers;
        this.bindings.TryGetValue(typeof(TResponse), out subscribers);

        // ERROR: How can I cast List<Subscriber<Response>> to List<Subscriber<TResponse>>?
        return subscribers;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help :)

> **EDIT 2**
>
> I changed the code according to @Bojan answer, and it is working. But
>   I am curious, why the Dictionary can't hold the base class of all
>   Response messages? Is there even a way to accomplish that, or did I
>   just tried to push my head through a wall?
>
> **EDIT 3**
>
> Now I am facing another problem ... when message arrive, it is
>   composed of byte array, >which goes to message factory which resolves
>   and builds it:

```
public static T Build<T>(Packet packet) where T : Response
{
    Type resolvedType;
    if (!dependencyMap.TryGetValue(packet.MessageId, out resolvedType))
    {
        var str = String.Format("Could not resolve message. Message info: CMD0: {0}, CMD1: {1}, MessageID: {2}",
                                packet.Cmd0, packet.Cmd1, packet.MessageId);
        Debug.WriteLine(str);

        throw new MessageNotFoundException(str);
    }

    ConstructorInfo firstConstructor = resolvedType.GetConstructors().First();

    return (T) firstConstructor.Invoke(new object[] {packet});
}
```

> Then an **OnAsyncResponseReceived(Response response)** event handler
>   is invoked, which then forwards message to the subscriber of this
>   message, if any. The problem is now that if I subscribe to (sub layer
>   of response are: AFResponse, SystemResponse, etc...)
>   SystemResetResponse which is subclass of SystemResponse which is
>   subclass of Response, that I must cast that response from
>   Response(base) type all the way to the concrete type, which is
>   SystemResetResponse in order the Forwarder in MessageBinder can find
>   subscribers of this message type, and forwards it.
>
> There are many types and casting by hand would be an overkill ... is
>   there a way around this, or even a better way to design this type of
>   system?
>
> **EDIT 4**
>
> I changed a code like this ... is this the right way to do this, is
>   there any other, better way and over all, am I trying to solve the
>   problem the right way or is there better way to handle this?

```
private void OnAsyncResponseReceived(Response response)
{
    dynamic resolvedResponse = Convert.ChangeType(response, response.GetType());
    messageBinder.Forward(resolvedResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you are trying to declare your dictionary as having generic subscribers (`List<Subscriber<Response>>`), while expecting each entry to be of an unrelated type (`List<Subscriber<TResponse>>`). A solution would be to hide the actual type behind `object` or `IList`:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> bindings;

private List<Subscriber<TResponse>> GetSubscribers<TResponse>() 
    where TResponse : Response
{
    object subscribers;
    bindings.TryGetValue(typeof(TResponse), out subscribers);

    return (List<Subscriber<TResponse>>)subscribers;
}
```

Your `Forward` method can check for `AFResponse` and subclasses in a bit easier way, but the cast will have to go through `object`:

```
public void Forward<TResponse>(TResponse response)
    where TResponse : Response
{
    var subscribers = GetSubscribers<TResponse>();
    if (subscribers != null)
    {
        Subscriber<TResponse> subscriber;

        var afResponse = response as AFResponse;
        if (afResponse != null)
        {
            subscriber = subscribers.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ShortAddress == afResponse.ShortAddress);
        }
        else
        {
            subscriber = subscribers.First();
        }

        if (subscriber != null)
        {
            subscriber.Forward(response);
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

You did not declare your dictionary to hold "base class of all messages". Even though `Response` is the base class of all responses, `Subscriber<Response>` and `Subscriber<T>` are unrelated types. It is somewhat analogous to how `List<int>` and `List<string>` are not related, even though both `string` and `int` inherit from `object`.

What you are looking for is called [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) and is only supported by some interfaces.

For example, if you had:

```
interface ISubscriber<out T> where T:Response
{}

class Subscriber<T> : ISubscriber<T> where T:Response
{}
```

You could do:

```
ISubscriber<Response> s = new Subscriber<AFResponse>();
```

However, `List<ISubscriber<Response>>` and `List<ISubscriber<AFResponse>>` would still be unrelated types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) But can you explain to me why the dictionary can't hold the base class of all messages as Response is a base class of all responses?

Comment: I have tried using covariance, but as you said, it does not aplay in my case, or does it? I am facing another problem now ... how can I cast response to it's concrete type durning runtime ... I describe the problem in edit #3. Thank you!

Comment: No, covariance does not apply in your case. As for the other problem, I think you'd best post it as a different question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast each item in `subscribers` list to `Subscriber<TResponse>`.
Something like this always works for me -

```
private List<T> get<T>()
    {
        List<IEntity> list = new List<IEntity>();
        List<T> genericList = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            genericList.Add((T)item);
        }
        return genericList;
    }
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

As well as the answer already provided, the following lines of code...

```
    Type responseType = typeof (TResponse);
    if (responseType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (AFResponse)))
```

Could be replaced with either:

```
    if (response is AFResponse)
```

or (better)

```
    AFResponse af = response as AFResponse;
    if (af != null)
```

**EDIT** Updated the code because I didn't realise beforehand that TResponse was a generic. Are you also aware that IsSubclassOf returns false if its a matching type?

Comment: I forgot to mention that Response and AFRsponse are abstract classes, so it never would be of that type. The class hierarchy is:


Response -> AFResponse -> Concrete implementation of AF layer messages